# "While" and "repeat" loops in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, loops, twig, cycle

Are there any nice ways to use while and repeat loops in Twig? It is such a simple task, but without macros I can't find anything nice and simple.

At least do an infinite cycle and then break it in a condition?

EDIT:

I mean something like

```
do {
    // loop code
} while (condition)
```

or

```
while (condition) {
    // loop code
}
```

Edit 2:

Looks like it is not supported natively by twig same reason as it is not supported neither `continue;` or `break;` statements.

https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/654

Comment: There's a `for` and `foreach` statement in Twig, also `if` conditions, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: Added some examples what I am looking exactly.

Comment: #Aistis I face the same issue... would need to use while(condition){ }... but seems that it's not available in TWIG. But you say that macro might be a way to do it. could you share more about it as I have never used macro with symfony so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a nutshell: no. This functionality implies advanced logic, which should be in your business logic, not in the template layer. It's a prime example of the separation of concerns in MVC.

Twig supports [`for`-loops](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) completely, which should suffice if you code correctly - being that complex conditional decisions on which data to display are taken in the business logic where they belong, which then pass a resulting array 'ready to render' to the templates. Twig then supports all nice features only needed for rendering.

Comment: The problem is that I need to print a nested array. There is a condition it has to be printed not recursively, but **iteratively**. I am not sure is it really so advanced logic that it should preprocessed in back-end.

Comment: You need neither `do` nor `while` to process a nested array in Twig. What you are looking to do is probably easily done with a simple macro. Makes this question a glaring [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though - you asked about your intended solution, not the real problem you're trying to solve. Now you leave me and the rest of us just guessing at what you *really* want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Niels for your concern, but **I was interesting does Twig really do not have the implementation** of `do` and `while`. With the comment above, I've just wanted to point out, that there are some cases where these types of cycles could be a clever choice. I am not looking the answer for my particular problem. Sorry if we have misunderstood t each other.

Comment: Well, that part was answered in the first four words of my answer  ;) Twig does not support features its designers consider to be 'out of scope' for a template engine, which includes these advanced looping constructs. It only supports `for` for looping - although that's very powerful when combined with range constructs and the like.

Comment: Some extra thoughts on loops with breaking. https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/654

Comment: I'm completely disagree. A do..while/while() loop isn't 'complex' it's a way to do something at least once and in DISPLAY LOGIC which doesn't mean I absolutely HAVE to make a giant pile of code to structure an array just to make my display work with the limited ability of for/foreach.

Answer (score 22):

You can emulate it with `for ... in ... if` by using a sufficiently-high loop limit (10000?)

## while

PHP:

```
$precondition = true;
while ($precondition) {
    $precondition = false;
}
```

Twig:

```
{% set precondition = true %}
{% for i in 0..10000 if precondition %}
    {% set precondition = false %}
{% endfor %}
```

## do while

PHP:

```
do {
    $condition = false;
} while ($condition)
```

Twig:

```
{% set condition = true %} {# you still need this to enter the loop#}
{% for i in 0..10000 if condition %}
    {% set condition = false %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: FYI: Nesting an if inside a for is no longer supported - [reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags)

Answer (score 11):

I was able to implement a simple for loop in twig. So the following php statement:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
}
```

when translated to twig is:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's not a while loop but a potential workaround. The best suggestion is to leave business logic like this out of the template layer.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how it is a replacement to a conditional loop.

Comment: what is your code is for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x+++)  ?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but a little bit complicated.

You can use `{% include ... %}` to process nested arrays, which from the comments I read is what you need to do.

Consider the following code:

`nested_array_display.html`

```
<ul>
{% for key, val in arr %}
    <li>
        {{ key }}:
{% if val is iterable %}
{% include 'nested_array_display.html' %}
{% else %}
        {{ val }}
{% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```