# How to loop while [expression] in TWIG

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I am trying to loop in twig. I find myself having to apply a workaround of unneccesary spins in a loop according to below workaround and am wondering if there isn't a simpler way to loop in twig?

I found this ["While" and "repeat" loops in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691672/while-and-repeat-loops-in-twig) but it is old and the syntax is no longer supported. FOR and IF now need to be split up in different statements (and already when that answer applied, it was still a workaround).

```
{% for i in 0..30 %}
    {% if counter < aircraft.HourArrival %}
    <TD width="3.5%"></TD>   
    {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Shouldn't there just be a simple way to do

```
{% while counter < aircraft.HourArrival %}
```

Comment: I think, twig doesn't provide a native while true loops to prevent potentially infinite loops.

Comment: FYI: You could create your own `while`-tag - [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#registering-a-new-tag)